# Hyperledger Composer Error Identity has not been registered once issued after restart

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am using hyperledger composer 0.16.0 and I want to persist data to database so that data can be used even after restart. so I am using `loopback-connector-mongodb`

### Context

I have been following [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html) tutorial and I am able to complete it.

I have setup fabric by issuing below steps

```
cd ${HOME}/fabric-tools/

 ./stopFabric.sh 
 ./teardownFabric.sh
./downloadFabric.sh
./startFabric.sh

cd ${HOME}/tmt/Profile/

composer card create -p connection.json -u PeerAdmin -c Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem -k 114aab0e76bf0c78308f89efc4b8c9423e31568da0c340ca187a9b17aa9a4457_sk -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin

composer card import -f PeerAdmin@fabric-network.card

composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network -n dam-network

cd ../dam-network/

# added model.cto file below
composer archive create -t dir -n .

composer network start -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network -a dam-network@0.0.1.bna -A admin -S adminpw

composer card import -f admin@dam-network.card

composer network ping -c admin@dam-network

chmod -R 777 ${HOME}/.composer 

## onetime setup using npm install -g loopback-connector-mongodb
docker run -d --name mongo --network composer_default -p 27017:27017 mongo

cd ${HOME}/tmt/docker

docker build -t myorg/my-composer-rest-server .

#Which is attached below

source envvars.txt

docker run \
    -d \
    -e COMPOSER_CARD=${COMPOSER_CARD} \
    -e COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=${COMPOSER_NAMESPACES} \
    -e COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION=${COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION} \
    -e COMPOSER_MULTIUSER=${COMPOSER_MULTIUSER} \
    -e COMPOSER_PROVIDERS="${COMPOSER_PROVIDERS}" \
    -e COMPOSER_DATASOURCES="${COMPOSER_DATASOURCES}" \
    -v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer \
    --name rest \
    --network composer_default \
    -p 3000:3000 \
    myorg/my-composer-rest-server
```

I issue a new identity, to an existing participant and I create a business card for this identity with the following command

```
composer participant add -c admin@dam-network -d ' {"$class": "com.asset.tmt.User","userId": "tmtadmin","email": "tmtadmin@gmail.com","firstName": "TMT","lastName": "Admin","userGroup": "peerAdmin"} ' 

composer identity issue -u tmtadmin -a com.asset.tmt.User#tmtadmin -c admin@dam-network 

composer card import -f tmtadmin@dam-network.card
```

Then, I import that business card via POST /wallet/import and I am able to call different REST API operations. After that, I stop the composer-rest-server and after a few minutes I start the composer-rest-server again with the commands

```
cd ${HOME}/fabric-tools/
./startFabric.sh
docker start mongo rest
```

Issuing above command is not working so I am killing rest and then running it again by issuing below commands. Correct me if I am wrong

```
 docker stop rest
 docker rm rest 
docker run \
    -d \
    -e COMPOSER_CARD=${COMPOSER_CARD} \
    -e COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=${COMPOSER_NAMESPACES} \
    -e COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION=${COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION} \
    -e COMPOSER_MULTIUSER=${COMPOSER_MULTIUSER} \
    -e COMPOSER_PROVIDERS="${COMPOSER_PROVIDERS}" \
    -e COMPOSER_DATASOURCES="${COMPOSER_DATASOURCES}" \
    -v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer \
    --name rest \
    --network composer_default \
    -p 3000:3000 \
    myorg/my-composer-rest-server
```

Then, I authenticate to the REST API using the configured authentication mechanism (in my case passport-github strategy) and if I try to call one operation for REST API it throws a A business network card has not been specified error message, then I import the previous business card via POST /wallet/import getting a no content which is supposed to be correct.

Finally, when I try to call another REST API operation I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{\"code\":400,\"message\":\"Authorization failure\"}]]",
    "stack": "Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{\"code\":400,\"message\":\"Authorization failure\"}]]\n    at client.getUserContext.then.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:305:34)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)"
  }
}
```

### Expected Behavior

```
This should work even after restart
```

### Actual Behavior

```
This is the main issue, I don't know why my identity is not being recognized by the REST API if I used it previously to call some operations.
```

### Your Environment

```
* Version used: 0.16.0
* Environment name and version (e.g. Chrome 39, node.js 5.4):  chrome latest and node.js 8.9.1
* Operating System and version (desktop or mobile): Ubuntu desktop
```

### My envvars.txt

```
COMPOSER_CARD=admin@dam-network
 COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=never
 COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION=true
 COMPOSER_MULTIUSER=true
 COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
    "github": {
        "provider": "github",
        "module": "passport-github",
        "clientID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "clientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "authPath": "/auth/github",
        "callbackURL": "/auth/github/callback",
        "successRedirect": "/",
        "failureRedirect": "/"
    }
}'
 COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
    "db": {
        "name": "db",
        "connector": "mongodb",
        "host": "10.142.0.10"
    }
}'
```

### model.cto

```
/**
 * Model Definitions
 */
namespace com.asset.tmt

participant User identified by userId {
  o String userId
  o String email
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  o String userGroup
}

asset Asset identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  o String name
  o String creationDate
  o String expiryDate
}

transaction ChangeAssetValue {
  o String expiryDate
  o String assetId
  o String userId
}
```

**update:**

After following what @R Thatcher told, When I issue command `docker-compose start` , it is starting fabric network but not the business network which is deployed earlier.

`tmt@blockchain:~/tmt/dam-network$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                            NAMES
8a6833bd7d3a        myorg/my-composer-rest-server                                                                                    "pm2-docker compos..."   17 hours ago        Exited (0) 10 hours ago                                                     rest
9bffab63a048        mongo                                                                                                            "docker-entrypoint..."   17 hours ago        Exited (0) 10 hours ago                                                     mongo
5bafb4dd5662        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-dam-network-0.16.0-4a77c4c8eabde9e440464f91b1655a48c6c5e0dac908e36a7b437034152bf141   "chaincode -peer.a..."   17 hours ago        Exited (0) 4 minutes ago                                                    dev-peer0.org1.example.com-dam-network-0.16.0
4bfc67f13811        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.4                                                                             "peer node start -..."   17 hours ago        Up 6 minutes               0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
762a42bc0eb7        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.4                                                                          "orderer"                17 hours ago        Up 6 minutes               0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
49c925a8cc43        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.4                                                                          "tini -- /docker-e..."   17 hours ago        Up 6 minutes               4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
cee51891308f        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.4                                                                               "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   17 hours ago        Up 6 minutes               0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com`

What is the correct way to bring it up?

1)When I try to start network by issuing below command

```
tmt@blockchain:~/tmt/dam-network$ composer network start -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network -a dam-network@0.0.1.bna -A admin -S adminpw
Starting business network from archive: dam-network@0.0.1.bna
Business network definition:
        Identifier: dam-network@0.0.1
        Description: Blockchain dam integration

Processing these Network Admins: 
        userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: chaincode exists dam-network)

Command failed
```

2) When I try to start docker container manually by issuing docker start container I still see it is not up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `startFabric.sh` does more than just start the Fabric - it actually removes your Containers and recreates new Containers from the Docker Images.  The impact of this is that you lose all your data and your Business Network from the Fabric.

If you want to stop and start your Fabric after you have created it you need to change to the directory where the `docker-compose.yml` file is (in my case `/home/rob/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer`)

Run `docker-compose stop` to stop the Fabric Containers and `docker-compose start` to restart where you left off.  It is necessary to be in the correct folder before using the docker-compose command.

Comment: @R Thatcher, I am able to bring docker fabric network up but not chaincode, I have updated the question with what I have done. can you please suggest next steps

Comment: You don't need to run the `composer network start` command again.  (and your error says "chaincode exists") 
If you ping the the business network, the container with the name of the network e.g. dev-peer0.org1.example.com-dam-network-0.16.0-... will be started automatically - no need to start it manually.
(ping is not the only command that will start that container - just the easiest.)

Comment: Thank you Thatcher, it worked and I am able to see previously persisted data However I am using docker rest server when issuing command docker start rest, it is not working so I am removing and then creating again. Is this correct way of doing?

Comment: If you look at the docker-compose.yml file you will see that it only controls the set of 4 containers that make up the development Fabric.  So you do need to manage the rest container separately with docker commands.