# Restart fabric composer without startFabric.sh

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want to restart hyperledger-composer docker containers without using startFabric.sh in order not to loose deployed networks.
Using docker-compose start under fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer directory starts all cointainers except the chaincode container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-...
When I try to start it I get this error:
***[ERROR] lib/handler.js - Chat stream with peer - on error: "Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error handling message, ending stream: transition canceled with error: peer will not accept external chaincode connection name:\"default:0.0.1\"  (except in dev mode)***

So I try
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml start
and then
docker start .... (the dev container)

But still the same error

¿Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can already find an answer by

1) searching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyperledger-composer

2) enter your search criteria after the square brackets [ ] up top in the search bar

3) click newest for the newest responses

Here is one result that should help you -> [How to restart the fabric composer without losing the existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data)

Answer (score 0):

[This previous Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767190/hyperledger-composer-error-identity-has-not-been-registered-once-issued-after-re/47771864#47771864) on the startFabric.sh script answers the basic question of how to start and stop the development Fabric without losing the data, or your existing Business Network.

Regarding he chaincode container with a name beginning 'dev-' - you don't need to start that container - it will be started on demand automatically when it is first accessed.  (if it was acidently deleted it will be re-created.)