# Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: make sure the chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am getting the below message every time when we connect business network from composer playground. First time is working. After restart the machine and try to connect the business network its not working

> Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: make sure the chaincode

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you restarted your Docker containers after restarting your m/c but I suspect this (state of your Docker containers) is where the problem lies (if indeed they're started at this point)

suggest to read this ANSWER section to know how to 'resume' after a m/c restart:

[Hyperledger Composer Error Identity has not been registered once issued after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767190/hyperledger-composer-error-identity-has-not-been-registered-once-issued-after-re/47771864#47771864)

As indicated there, you can ping the business network, with an existing business network card  (once the Fabric network is up) and its chaincode container will be started.